# Dynamic rule file(.drl) generation from database using Rule Template

Tags: drools, apache-storm, rule

We generated the rule file from database using the Rule Template , it is working but we are facing one problem i.e the rules in the rule generated as much as records present in the table.So according my requirement it should not generate rule files based on records present in the tables.

Rule Template:

```
template header
alert_playload
package com.trinity;
import com.trinity.DroolsBolt;
import com.trinity.Tuplebean;
dialect "mvel"
template "sensorRule"
rule "Safety Alert"
    when
       t : Tuplebean(@{alert_playload})
    then
DroolsBolt.insertToAlertLog(t.getSmokeKey().toString(),t.getMacAddress().toString());     
end

end template
```

Drools Bolt logic:

```
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://52.172.14.126:5432/iotdb",
                            "postgres", "track@123");
          Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
      String sql="SELECT min_threshould , max_threshould , sensor_name , alert_playload FROM iot.alert_configuration WHERE drools_boolean=true and alert_configuration_id=94";
      ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);
      final ResultSetGenerator converter = new ResultSetGenerator();
      final String drl = converter.compile(rs, getRulesStream());
      System.out.println(drl);
      sta.close();
      KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder =
                KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
      kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drl.getBytes()),
                     ResourceType.DRL);
      KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
      kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
      StatefulKnowledgeSession kSession = 
         kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
   /*// now create some test data
      Sensor a = new Sensor("A", 100);     
      Sensor b = new Sensor("B", 520);
      Sensor c = new Sensor("C", 610);
      kSession.insert(a); 
      kSession.insert(b);   
      kSession.insert(c);
      kSession.fireAllRules();
      System.out.println(a.getName() + "," + a.getThreshould());
      System.out.println(b.getName() + "," + b.getThreshould());
      System.out.println(c.getName() + "," + c.getThreshould());
      kSession.destroy();      
      kSession.dispose();
      kSession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
      Sensor aa = new Sensor("AA", 820); 
      Sensor bb = new Sensor("BB", 200);
      Sensor cc = new Sensor("CC", 141);
      kSession.insert(aa);
      kSession.insert(bb);    
      kSession.insert(cc);*/
   //   kSession.destroy();      
    //  kSession.dispose();
 //     kSession.fireAllRules();
      /*System.out.println(aa.getName() + "," + aa.getName());
      System.out.println(bb.getName() + "," + bb.getName());
      System.out.println(cc.getName() + "," + cc.getName());*/
      //kSession.fireAllRules();

      try {
          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/IotHub/conf/alert.drl"));
          out.write(drl.toString());
          out.close();
          }
          catch (IOException e){
          System.out.println("Exception ");
          }


      kSession.destroy();      
      kSession.dispose();
      kSession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
      kSession.fireAllRules();
```

Generated rule file is:

```
rule "sensorRule_2"
    when
       $sensor : Sensor(getThreshould()>=0)
    then
      $sensor.sensor_name=":" + "Generator Fuel Level";
end

rule "sensorRule_1"
    when
       $sensor : Sensor(getThreshould()>=0)
    then
      $sensor.sensor_name=":" + "motion";
end

rule "sensorRule_0"
    when
       $sensor : Sensor(getThreshould()>=0)
    then
      $sensor.sensor_name=":" + "smke";
end
```

Comment: These rules are not derived from the template. The RHS is completely different, `t : Tuplebean` doesn't match `$sensor : Sensor` and not even the rule name is right.

Comment: Thank you , We got solution but actually we putted wrong rule file. but now we are able to generate the dynamic rule file from database.                             Rule Template:

Comment: template header
sensor_name
package com.sample;
import com.sample.Tuplebean;
dialect "mvel"
template "ageRule"
rule "ageRule_@{row.rowNumber}"
when
$s: Tuplebean(@{sensor_name})

then
System.out.println("drools is coming*******************");
end
end template

Comment: Rule generated is:                                                                                                  package com.sample;
import com.sample.Tuplebean;
dialect "mvel"

rule "ageRule_0"
when
$s: Tuplebean(temp > 10 &&  motion = true)
then
System.out.println("drools is coming*******************");
end

Comment: If you still have a problem, fix the syntax (use `==` and not `=`) and if the problem persists, delete this question and start another one.

Comment: Yes thank you laune..i replaced the == instead of = now it is working fine.